# angular js set use $on without $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i see in angular there is two way for set controller.
The old:

```
app.controller('my_ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.a = null;
}]);
```

and this one:

```
app.controller('my_ctrl',function(){
      this.a = null;
});
```

now i try to use the $on listener and int the docs they use it with $scope. I tried to use it like this:

> this.$on

but i have this error:

```
this.$on is not a function
```

how can i use $on in the second way please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you use `$on` is by using it on the `$scope` variable itself not the `this` pointer.

try this out.

`$scope.$on('listener', function() {})`

So for your example

```
app.controller('my_ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('listener', function() {
    // do stuff on the event
  })
})
```

Comment: adding to what ericraio said - you only need $scope when you're watching a variable for changes or whatever. Event monitoring can't be done on "this"

Comment: ok thanks i thought if we uses this now that same that use $scope. Then i thought i cant use $scope.

Comment: @user3699170 yeah keep in mind that using this newer way with controllers can cause issues if you minimize all your javascript together in one file. There is a gulp/grunt plugin to re-write all your files back to the old version in the minification process. The newer syntax is much nicer.